# How to access Global Variables in C

Tags: c, function, structure

I am trying to populate global variables but it seems to not be working . Here is my code .

```
typedef struct Global_ {

char values[3][40]

}Global_t;
//function file

GBL_PTR = calloc (1, sizeof (Global_t));
memset(GBL_PTR.values,'\0',sizeof(GBL_PTR.values));

//opening a file and reading it

sscanf(linebuf, "List of values %s , %s \n",
               GBL_PTR.values[0],
               GBL_PTR.values[1]);
printf("Why dont i see these logs %s",GBM_PTR.values[1]);
```

I don't see any crashes , just no logs. The compiles fine. I am new to C, can someone let me know what am I missing here. The main idea is to access a global variable from my function. How do I do it?

Comment: Can you specify the declaration of GBL_PTR  ?

Comment: No crashes; compiles fine; What is the problem then? Also, where are the global variables and where are the functions that initialize them (or where is their global initialization)?

Comment: If it s a pointer you cannot access GBL_PTR.values .. is your program is compling? .. it should be GBL_PTR->values

Comment: You initialize data referenced by `GBL_PTR`; you print data referenced by `GBM_PTR`.  What did you expect?  If this isn't the exact code you're having problems with, how are we supposed to help you debug it?

Comment: Please give us code that we can compile ourself without modifying anything.

Comment: Check the return of `sscanf()`... and note that the text you have in the `sscanf()` format string needs to be part of your input or it'll stop reading values..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some errors in you code,
(1) you miss a semicolon after `char values[3][40]`

(2) the return type of `calloc` is `void*`, so use `Global_t* GBL_PTR = (Global_t*)calloc (1, sizeof (Global_t));`

(3) because the type of `GBL_PTR` is an pointer, so you can access `values` like this:`GBL_PTR->values` or `(*GBL_PTR)values`.

```
typedef struct Global_ {

    char values[3][40];

}Global_t;
//function file

Global_t* GBL_PTR = (Global_t*)calloc (1, sizeof (Global_t));
memset(&(GBL_PTR->values),'\0',sizeof(GBL_PTR->values));

//opening a file and reading it
char* linebuf= "List of values wang , yang \n";
sscanf(linebuf, "List of values %s , %s \n",
    GBL_PTR->values[0],
    GBL_PTR->values[1]);
printf("Why dont i see these logs %s\n", GBL_PTR->values[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the type of GBL_PTR, it should be:

```
Global_t *GBL_PTR = calloc(1, sizeof (Global_t));
```

GBL_PTR is a pointer so use the `->`operator instead of the `.` operator everywhere.

```
GBL_PTR->values
GBL_PTR->values[0]
```

etc...